# Vue - Using localStorage to hold a theme not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

This issue has confused me while developing a Vue site for some time now and I haven't been able to resolve my particular bug with other threads.
The idea should be simple, have a switch that toggles a value between 'light' and 'dark', and bind the class to that value.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class='themeValue'>
    <!-- Switch component from Buefy UI !-->
    <b-switch size='is-large' type='is-dark' v-model='theme'></b-switch>
    <!-- Other components !-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      theme: localStorage.getItem('theme') || false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    theme: function() {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    themeValue: function() {
      return this.theme ? 'light' : 'dark'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import './_variables.scss';

.dark {
  color: $light;
  background-color: $background;
}

.light {
  color: $dark;
  background-color: $lightbackground;
}
</style>
```

I have tried what feels like a million different variations of the above, including using `mounted()` to set `this.theme`, holding all the logic in an external component and using `$emit`, etc.

The expected behavior is to default to dark theme unless localStorage holds a value for 'theme', in which case to default to that. The switch component should match the state of the theme always (i.e. if saved to light theme, the switch should default to `true`).

The behavior of the above code does is to always default to light theme, and the switch defaults to false. Those two being out of sync (light theme is applied when `theme === true`), the first switch press doesn't change the theme but does change itself to `true`, and subsequent presses work correctly (`true` applies `.light` class, `false` applies `.dark`)

EDIT: localStorage was storing the true/false values as strings. You could do a nice implementation with JSON.parse I think, but I ended up just using a `mounted` with `if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'true')` and it works fine. Needless to say I'm really mad at myself that this took 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is how i got it working locally, i switched around the or statement and changed the property name to themes.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class='themeValue'>
    <!-- Switch component from Buefy UI !-->
    <button size='is-large' type='is-dark' @click='themes = !themes'>klik</button>
    <!-- Other components !-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      themes: false || localStorage.getItem('theme')
    }
  },
  watch: {
    theme: function() {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    themeValue: function() {
      return this.themes ? 'light' : 'dark'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">


.dark {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.light {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

So i suggest you change the name of your watch function to something like updateTheme, and switch the conditional statement in your data property and then it should work :)

Comment: Unfortunately changing to a `button` oversimplifies the problem as it is getting the `b-switch` element to be in the correct configuration is key to the design. As I said earlier, the switch correctly executes its logic, the app just isn't loading its initial state correctly.

That said, I changed the switch to have `@input='updateTheme' :value='theme'` and replaced the `watch` property with the method `updateTheme () 
{ this.theme=!this.theme; localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme) }` as a take on your implementation and it still defaults to light theme =/

Comment: Okay, so what you can do is change your @input to `@input="theme = !theme"` and then have your watcher watch for the change in theme and update your localstorage like so `updateTheme () { localStorage.setItem('theme', this.theme) }`. If you then set your default to false it should default dark.

Comment: This still didn't work on my machine, but I found the bug. I will edit the original post. Thank you for your help kind stranger!

Comment: Oh duh, ofcourse it stores it as a string hahaha. Totally didnt notice that, good that you managed to find out :)